# How to fix issue mounting Synology share in Docker using Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, synology

I created a Docker image called `mytensorflow:1.13.1` and it loads fine. I now want to mount a share so that I can access my datasets located on a shared folder on a Synology DS218+. Note: I am using a Linux container.

I'm currently having difficulty mounting a Synology share that is mapped to m:\ in Windows.  I have no difficulty mounting my C:\ or even a USB drive. I also do not have any trouble accessing the m:\ via my File Manager.

I use the following command:

`docker run -it -v m:\:\home mytensorflow:1.13.1`

and I'm prompted with a messagebox that says:

#### Docker wants to access drive m:\, Do you want to share it?

I click the  "Share it" button and get a Windows Password Dialog with my Windows username pre-entered.

When I enter my Windows pasword, I get the following message:

#### Error response from daemon:  Drive sharing failed for an unknown reason.

When I tried entering the username/password combination to my Synology share, I get a message that I entered an "Invalid login/password". I verified it to be correct.

When I enter the Docker settings / Shared Drives, I only see my C drive and D drive (USB). I do not see my m:\ even though it shows up in File Manager.